# What's a good way to handle builtin functions in an interpreter written in C++?

Tags: c++, interpreter

I'm writing an interpreter in C++ for a lisp-like language of my humble design. This is for fun and for learning, so I'm not after absolute efficiency. But I am trying to have a very clean C++ code. I'm currently wondering how to implement builtin functions.

Basically, what I do is this :

I have an abstract base class DataObject which just provides type information (currently double, int, bool) and is inherited by the specific data containers, like :

```
class DataObject
{
public:
    virtual const Type *type() = 0;
};

template<class T, const Type * myType>
class DataObjectValue : public DataObject
{
T value;
public:
    const Type *type(){return myType;}
};
```

But then, when I want to perform say an addition I have to do things like :

```
DataObject * sum(DataObject *a, DataObject *b)
{
    if(a->type() == &Integer and b->type == &Integer)
    {
        DataObjectValue<int>* ia = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<int>* >(a);
        DataObjectValue<int>* ib = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<int>* >(b);
        return new DataObjectValue<int>(ia->value+ib->value);
    }
    else if(a->type() == &Real and b->type == &Real)
    {
        DataObjectValue<double>* ra = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<double>* >(a);
        DataObjectValue<double>* rb = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<double>* >(b);
        return new DataObjectValue<double>(ra->value+rb->value);
    }
    else...
}
```

Which gets pretty annoying pretty quickly (do that for - * / < <= >= < > ....) and for several other types. This is hard to maintain. Of course I have simplified as much of the process as I could think of by introducing lots of templates everywhere, but still, I can't help but to think there must be a cleaner way. Do you a) see what my problem is (I doubt my explaining, not your competence) b) have any suggestion?

Comment: How about make `DataObjectValue` a union? That way, you can check if `a.typy() == b.type()` and then use a `swtich`. It doesn't increase the performance (that is, it's basically the same algorithm), but you'd have substantially cleaner code.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no escaping the cases. You could put them in some other file you write once and never look at again so it doesn't clutter up your more important code.

Comment: @Shahbaz actually a `switch` can turn into a jump table but I don't think a series of `if`/`else if`s can be.

Comment: One strategy I have used for making such verbose and repetitive code maintainable is to write a much smaller and simpler Python script to generate that C++ code.

Comment: @SethCarnegie of course. That wasn't the main focus here though so I wasn't going to complicate things.

Comment: Python script looks nice, but I wanted to do it in pure C++ as much as possible - same reason why I do not like too much using macros for this. I know macros are C++, but, hmm... I don't like writing code for which the auto-completion doesnt work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation that you have basically performs type erasure in the exact type that is being stored, and you are doing it in a slightly unusual way (why don't you use an enum rather than pointers to unique objects?)

I would start by providing *promotion* operations to the base class, and have them implemented in each level:

```
enum DataType {
   type_bool,
   type_int,
   type_double
};

struct DataObject {
   virtual ~DataObject() {}    // remember to provide a virtual destructor if you
                               // intend on deleting through base pointers!!!
   virtual DataType type() const = 0;
   virtual bool   asBool() const = 0;
   virtual int    asInt() const = 0;
   virtual double asDouble() const = 0;
};
```

Then you can implement the operations in a simple functor:

```
template <typename T>
T sum_impl( T lhs, T rhs ) {
   return lhs + rhs;
}
```

And provide a simple dispatch function:

```
DataType promoteTypes( DataType lhs, DataType rhs ) {
   if ( lhs == type_double || rhs == type_double ) {
      return type_double;
   } else if ( lhs == type_int || rhs == type_int ) {
      return type_int;
   } else {
      return type_bool;
   }
}
template <template <typename T> T operation (T,T)>
DataObject* perform_operation( DataObject* lhs, DataObject* rhs, operation op ) const {
   DataType result_type = promoteTypes( lhs->type(), rhs->type() );
   switch ( result_type ) {
   case type_double: 
      return new DataObjectValue<double>( op( lhs->asDouble(), rhs->asDouble() );
   case type_int:
      return new DataObjectValue<int>( op( lhs->asInt(), rhs->asInt() );
   case type_bool:
      return new DataObjectValue<bool>( op( lhs->asBool(), rhs->asBool() );
   default:
      abort();
   }
}
```

With all the pieces in place, you can implement the operations almost trivially, by just providing a function template for the specific operation (as the `sum` above), and then using the rest of the places:

```
// sum_impl as above
DataObject* sum( DataObject* lhs, DataObject* rhs ) {
   return perform_operation( lhs, rhs, sum_impl );
}
```

Now that is just the pattern I would use, but I would make some changes, I prefer to use as few pointers as possible, which means that I would not pass the arguments by pointer but rather by reference. Also, I would do proper type erasure (take a look at boost any) and make `Object` a *complete* type that contains `DataObject` elements, and then perform the operations on that type (rather than the hierarchy). That will enable you to provide functions that also return by value (and hide the dynamic memory allocations internally, which also means that resource management can be controlled inside `Object` and is not the responsibility of user code). With those changes, you can reuse and simplify the structure above and provide a cleaner solution.

Comment: I like this one a lot, it is closer, though much more elegant, to the non stripped down version of my actual code. Thank you for the various pointers to interesting subjects, I'll have a deeper look into this! I am not too much worried about the pointers though, as these classes are derived from a class for which I have implemented ref-counting (since the expression trees tend to become hard to manage manually).

Comment: Depending on how your language is to evolve (i.e. if some of the operations cannot be performed on particular combinations of types) you might want to move into more complex solutions. As of the pointers, I would still consider it, if not for anything else it makes the code easier to reason about (i.e. you know that NULL is not a valid argument to any of the functions, no need to remember whether a particular pointer is already wrapped in a reference counting smart pointer somewhere --unless you modify all the interfaces to use that reference counted pointer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a macro aproach:

(I left the `\` for brevity)

```
#define IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR(name, operator)
DataObject * name(DataObject *a, DataObject *b)
{
    if(a->type() == &Integer and b->type == &Integer)
    {
        DataObjectValue<int>* ia = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<int>* >(a);
        DataObjectValue<int>* ib = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<int>* >(b);
        return new DataObjectValue<int>(ia->value operator ib->value);
    }
    else if(a->type() == &Real and b->type == &Real)
    {
        DataObjectValue<double>* ra = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<double>* >(a);
        DataObjectValue<double>* rb = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<double>* >(b);
        return new DataObjectValue<double>(ra->value operator rb->value);
    }
    else...
}
```

now, after this you can do this:

```
IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR(sum, +);
IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR(multiply, *);
IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR(division, /);
...
```

This would be fast and maintainable, but maybe problematic for special operators.

**EDIT:** Shahbaz mentioned that you can use Macros within other Macros. This can be applied in the following manner.

(again, `\`s left out for brevity)

```
#define IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR_TYPE(typeobject, internal_type, operator)
if(a->type() == &typeobject and b->type == &typeobject)
{
    DataObjectValue<internal_type>* ia = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<internal_type>* >(a);
    DataObjectValue<internal_type>* ib = dynamic_cast< DataObjectValue<internal_type>* >(b);
    return new DataObjectValue<internal_type>(ia->value operator ib->value);
}
```

Which can now be used within the `IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR` macro:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR(name, operator)
DataObject * name(DataObject *a, DataObject *b)
{
    IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR_TYPE(&Integer, int, operator);
    IMPLEMENT_OPERATOR_TYPE(&Real, double, operator);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Macros to the rescue! You could even use macros inside the macro for each case.

Comment: Good point, each type within the operator can also be declared with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

If the two operands have to be the same type, then you can try this:

```
class DataObject
{
public:
    virtual const Type *type() = 0;
    virtual DataObject *operator+(DataObject&) = 0;
    virtual DataObject *operator-(DataObject&) = 0;
    virtual DataObject *operator*(DataObject&) = 0;
    virtual DataObject *operator/(DataObject&) = 0;
};

template<class T, const Type * myType>
class DataObjectValue : public DataObject
{
    typedef DataObjectValue<T, myType> selfType;
    T value;
public:
    const Type *type(){return myType;}
    DataObject *operator+(DataObject& other) {
        if (other.type() != myType)
            return null;
        selfType &otherValue = static_cast<selfType&>(other);
        return new selfType(value + otherValue.value);
    }
    // etc.
};
```

Things get hairier when you start allowing int + double though. In some cases you can deal with that by checking all the types you know about (i.e. have already been declared), otherwise passing yourself to the other object:

```
if (other.type() != myType)
    return other + *this; // assume *other is a <double> that knows how to add an <int>
```